# Good textbooks to study the Sample design

Tags: sampling, references

I am going to write some tests on advanced topics on Statistical sample survey methodologies, which includes following topics like below

*Simple random sampling, Systematic sampling, PPS sampling, Stratified sampling.
Ratio and regression methods of estimation. Non-sampling errors, Non-response bias*

What are textbooks that a good university refers for above topics? Textbook with lot of worked-out solutions would be very good.

Comment: By "sample design" do you mean "study design" or "sample size calculation"?

Comment: These topics are all covered in Cochran's classic textbook, *Sampling Techniques* (1977).  I therefore doubt they would be considered "advanced."

Comment: I think it is beneficial to also know about multi-armed bandit approaches (e.g. [Villar *et al* 2015](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4856206/)). I'm not aware yet of a good book for introducing it. Design and multi-armed bandits are often taught separately.

Comment: Lohr's Sampling Design and Analysis pretty accessible

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/recommend-references-on-survey-sample-weighting